# How to write a function inside a declaration

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to get the "alt" property text on a image to display as title when using fancybox

HTML

```
<a href='inlinePicture'........
   <img alt='Awesome text'......
</a
```

JQUERY

```
$('.inlinePicture').facybox({
  title: $(this).find('img').attr('alt')
});
```

Problem is that the title is displaying "$(this).find('img').attr('alt')" instead of "Awesome text", what em I doing wrong?

I've also tried :

```
$('.inlinePicture').facybox({
   titleFormat: function (title) {
        return $(this.orig).siblings('p').text() || title;
    }
```

Comment: try to assign the alt text to a variable and then use it

Comment: @rutwikreddy stupid question, but is there a way to write the variable inside the "declaraton"

Comment: I think you've pared things down too much for the question, because fundamentally, what you have there should work provided you're running your jQuery code after the element exists. I certainly can't see how you'd get the code *as text* as you've described.. The symptom you're describing is quite strange. Can you post a more complete example, ideally an *entirely* complete self-contained example? (In the question itself, but a live version on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net *as well* is always nice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fancyBox v2 -

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeLoad : function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found the same solution when making the jfiddle example. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$('.inlinePicture').facybox({
  title: function() {
      return $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
  }
});
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Indeed, just a style thing; I much prefer the `find` version. (And note that `$('img', this)` will eventually call `$(this).find('img')` under the covers of the `$.fn.init` function.)

Comment: @Jivings It did not work. The title still gets "function() { return $(this).find('img').attr('alt'); }" instead of "awesome text".  Your example is actually the first thing I wrote myself, but didnt manage it to work properly. But thanks alot for the answer

Comment: @ Jivings: The thing is, this doesn't match his symptom. He said *"Problem is that the title is displaying "$(this).find('img').attr('alt')" instead of "Awesome text", what em I doing wrong?"*. If your answer were correct, he should be getting nothing, not `"$(this).find('img').attr('alt')"`.